# Building coded ui test project fails when "Perform runtime contract checking" is set to "full"

Tags: msbuild, code-contracts, coded-ui-tests, ccrewrite

I have a simple Test project where a CodedUITestMethod is created. The test method simply clicks the Windows Start button in the taskbar. The method is generated by the *Coded UI Test Builder* tool from Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Then, I go to project's *Properties* page, *Code Contracts* tab. 
Check the *Perform Runtime Contract Checking* check box. 
Change the value of *Contract Reference Assembly* combo box to "Build".

Now I hit F6 to build the project and receive the 2 errors:
Reading assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting' resulted in errors.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\MsBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.CodeContracts.targets (240,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ ccrewrite" "@CodedUITest_Contract2ccrewrite.rsp"" exited with code -1.

I have uploaded my project zip file to [my codeplex project](http://jacobsuibowen.codeplex.com/releases/view/70308#DownloadId=260561)

Could someone download the project and see if they can reproduce the compile error? Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5610426/60761

Comment: Since it's a simple project, can you post the parts with the Contracts (in context) ?

Comment: And sorry but -1 because when I took the trouble to browse the code on Plex I couldn't find any Contract calls.

Comment: @Henk
I deliberately post the project without the contracts. The project won't compile without any use of contracts. Could you reproduce the compile error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. It appears that Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll references another dll that is not added into the project.

Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.dll in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ solves the issue.

Thanks to [David K Allen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/david%20k%20allen/) who answered the question on the [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/fe96c0ba-5096-465b-ba6d-ce194d5d602d/).