# Code Contract : ccrewrite exited with code -1073741571

Tags: c#, code-contracts, ccrewrite

I use code contracts and local build with VS 2013 is fine, but on build server i get the next error:
`MSB3073: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\MsBuild\v14.0\Microsoft.CodeContracts.targets(642,5): The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccdocgen.exe" "@obj\Release\QuickGraphccdocgen.rsp"" exited with code -1073741571.`

How can i fix it?

I know about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610426/code-contract-ccrewrite-exited-with-code-1) and that -1073741571 is code for Stack overflow / exhaustion. My question is what may be a cause of problem. Why local build works fine but remote does not?

Thanks.

Comment: You are running the MSBuild version that is included with VS2015, not the one for VS2013.  Which is v12.0.  You can file this bug at connect.microsoft.microsoft.com.  Be sure to not take the shortcut you made in this question, include repro code.

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts/issues/169